# How to change VectorDrawable viewportHeight and viewportWidth and what is the best practice on working with vector?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, vector

> My Scenario

I download SVG from flaticon and change to vector asset in the Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio.

> My Problem

Everything is worked fine. While I use many icon for my Navigation View. These vectors are different size. Their viewportWidth and viewportHeight are different. As I want is all these vectors with the same size, I use android:width and android:height to 24dp but their sizes are different.

I find a lot and what I know is that viewportWidth and viewportHeight are the canvas size while drawing SVG and its not effect on SVG's size? So what can I do in my problem?

Comment: It's batter to resize vector image by third party editor before implement to android. 
sketch is very powerful editor for mac. please try to resize before user. 
https://sketchapp.com/docs/vector-editing/

Comment: Put some code and result so everyone can understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, Vector images are just having viewport width and height because it has to draw path.

If width and height will be increased, the path will be change.

So you do not need to change viewportWidth and viewportHeight but you can specify width/height in your layout.

For example :

The following example will display image with size of **56x56** and it will not be stretch as it uses vector image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector" />
```

Hope it will helps you.

Do let me know if you have any question.